# Java VM Options issue with OnError cmd command 'C:\Program' is not recognized'

Tags: java, cmd, crash, virtual-machine, command-line-arguments

To create windbg dump the following code fails to be executed after the Crash in the windows 10:

```
java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xms3m -Xmx3m -XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError "-XX:OnError=\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\windbg.exe\" -pv -p %p -c \".dump /f C:\Users\User\Desktop\toUpdate\osDump\osDump_%p.dump\"" jvm_tuning.gc.GcInvest
```

[The issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykwJx.png)

Update: In addition to that if we avoid escaping than we get the issue with the vmoptions ("Error: Could not find or load main class Files Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files")

Comment: it can't work with the spaces in the path

Comment: Without excaping this there would be another error with recognition of the vm options:
"Error: Could not find or load main class Files
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files"